# Aggregate distant relationship with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, eloquent

I have two models User and Child.

```
class User extends Model {
  public function children() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Child', 'user_child')->withPivot('relation_id');
  }
  public function connections() {
    // How to get the distinctly aggregate of my children.friends.contacts as a relationship here?
  }
}

class Child extends Model {
  public function contacts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_child')->withPivot('relation_id');
  }
  public function friends() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Child', 'child_connection', 'child_id1', 'child_id2');
  }
}
```

I would like to eagerly load the distant relationship which I name 'connections' which are the contacts (users) of my children's friends.

```
$user = User::with('children', 'children.friends', 'connections');
```

Any ideas how to do this elegantly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public function connections() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Child', 'user_id')->with('friends.contacts;);
}
```

OMG What a long shot!
If by any miracle that works, then doing

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->connections(); //should bring 'children', 'friends' and 'contacts' in one query.
```

Well it should.

If you find an answer, please post it. I'm really interested in this.

Comment: I changed it to 'children.friends.contacts' but it still does not give the right result. I want only the contacts of my children friends. Thanks for the effort though!